# Indicate an error condition in an ObjC call when return value is needed for something else

Tags: objective-c, methods, exception, return-value, nserror

What is the correct way in Objective-C to indicate an error condition when the return value is needed to indicate success or failure?

To be more clear, my return value is already set apart for indicating whether the method accomplishes a certain task, and it is handy for code readability when program-flow is concerned.  For example if you implement:

```
-(bool) didFinishTest;
```

you can go on to write:

```
if ([Student didFinishTest])
{
   // ... do something
}
```

But of course some kind of failure could occur during the execution of the method.  In the Android version of my app, I simply throw a custom exception when an unexpected failure occurs in the implementation.  Apple docs however seem to discourage this use in production code.  Yet in Apple's suggested use of `NSError` they recommend using the return value to indicate the presence of failure and the `NSError` object convey information about the error.  In the example above, this would prevent me from using the return value to indicate whether the student finished the test or not.

I can of course figure a way to address this, but my question to the community here is, Is there a best or recommended way of doing so, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a reference to `NSError` pointer, to add description of failure.

The [Apple "Programming With Objective-C" guide says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html):

> Some Cocoa and Cocoa Touch API pass back errors by reference. [...]
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)aURL
>        options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask
>          error:(NSError **)errorPtr;
> ```
>
> Before you call this method, you’ll need to create a suitable pointer so that you can pass its address:
>
> ```
>  NSError *anyError;
>  BOOL success = [receivedData writeToURL:someLocalFileURL
>                                  options:0
>                                    error:&anyError];
>  if (!success) {
>      NSLog(@"Write failed with error: %@", anyError);
>      // present error to user
>  }
> ```

if an error occurs, the writeToURL:... method will return NO, and update your anyError pointer to point to an error object describing the problem.

> When dealing with errors passed by reference, it’s important to test
>   the return value of the method to see whether an error occurred, as
>   shown above. Don’t just test to see whether the error pointer was set
>   to point to an error.

Comment: Tiko, In my question I mentioned how Apple recommends what you described in the particular case that the return value is free (unused). I'm looking for a solution when the return value is already being used for something else.

Comment: In this case return value is free, you can return anything you want, this method returns BOOL, but you can return any type you wish, for example `AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error ];` returns 
 object of type AVCaptureDeviceInput

Answer (score 0):

Within the called method set the returned `NSError` to `nil` on success, to an error object on failure. In the caller test the error return against `nil`. HTH

Comment: I upvoted your answer since it was so concise, but I credited Tiko with correct answer bc he beat you (barely) to the punch.

Comment: Generally, the `NSError**` argument should be an optional parameter;  passing in NULL means "I only want to know success/failure, don't bother calculating why.".

Comment: @bbum - I agree, "generally", but when the return value has no room to indicate failure then *requiring* the parameter not be `NULL` is a reasonable exception which proves the rule.